# How to dynamically bind multiple parameters on SQL query in python?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, pymysql

So, I've a table (say `table_name` ) and it columns are:

```
|  A   |  B   |  C   |
------------------------
|  a1  |  b1  |  c1  |
|  a2  |  b2  |  c2  |
   ...
```

Now i have to read a column data using following query:

```
import pandas as pd
import pymysql as pycon

con = pycon.connect(host='localhost',user='root',password='', db='database')

#Error in here
df= pd.read_sql_query("SELECT A from table_name where B = %s and C != %s" %variableB %variableC, con)
```

But I've encountered an error in `read_sql_query(...)` maybe the query format is wrong because dynamically binded single parameter works fine
i.e

```
df= pd.read_sql_query("SELECT A from table_name where B = %s" %variableB, con)
```

works w/o error. Can anyone help me with the query?

Comment: Try `df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT A from table_name where B = %s and C != %s" % (variableB, variableC), con)
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case someone ran into same problem, the correct code for query was with a `'%s'` instead of `%s`

```
df= pd.read_sql_query("SELECT A from table_name where B = '%s' and C != '%s'" % (variableB, variableC), con)
```

the code below gave me pymysql.err.InternalError.

```
df= pd.read_sql_query("SELECT A from table_name where B = %s and C != %s" % (variableB, variableC), con)
```

Thank you stackOverflow :)

Answer (score 1):

when you bind your multiple variable into String, syntax should be like this

```
df= pd.read_sql_query("SELECT A from table_name where B = %s and C != %s" % (variableB, variableC), con)
```

Comment: It gave me  pymysql.err.InternalError working now. All i had to do was replace `%s` with `'%s'` in your code. I have posted a solution as answer below. Thanks for your help